# Log text in the console of another webpage

Tags: javascript, html, logging, console

Is it possible to log something in the console of another webpage? Below is a snippet of what I have so far:

```
function openWindowX() {
    var x = window.open("www.example.com");
}
function writeInConsoleX() {
    x.console.log(document.body.innerHTML = "new content");
}
```

But this doesn't always work. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You should open URI at the same domain. Otherwise your code works fine.